# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 using C++ classes

Tags: c++, object

I've read the other questions on this topic but still haven't figured out how to fix my issue

Thank you in advance for your help!

My error is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "Record::Record(std::__1::vector, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator > > >, double*)", referenced from:
>         _main in akh70P3ClassTester-946637.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

## Record.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Record
{
public:
    Record();
    Record(vector<string> , double []);

private:
    //some variables
};
```

## Record.cpp

```
#include "Record.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

Record::Record() {}

Record::Record(vector<string> inputs, double num_inputs[] )
{
    //variables happens
}
```

## Main.cpp

```
#include "Record.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<string> inputs;

    double num_inputs[] = {};

    Record temp(inputs, num_inputs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how are you compiling this program? please include your makefile if you have one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I saw the tag for objective-c, is this being compiled via Xcode?

Comment: @NonCreature0714 I compiled it using SublimeText2 which is telling me it used this shell command:

g++ "main.cpp" -o "main" && "main" (i omitted the full file path)

so I think Syntactic Fructose's answer is right, because it isn't compiling report.cpp. I am testing it right now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably aren't including Report.cpp in your compilation, e.g. only doing `g++ main.cpp -o main`

Instead, compile your program by including the report files: `g++ main.cpp report.cpp -o main`

Comment: You were right. I wasn't using a makefile because I didn't know what that is until googling just now after your question. I was using SublimeText2's single file C++ build and run function( via Cmd-B). compiling via Terminal with the line you gave me worked and it makes sense.
Thanks!